# TabHost inside dialog ..?

Tags: android, dialog, android-tabhost

Can I use TabHost inside Dialog. my application extends activity (Not Tab-Activity).
and another problem is that how to call a function when the tab is pressed.

plz give me simple example of it.

thanks in advance

Comment: plz help me .... frndzzzz....

Answer (score 6):

Yes we can call the Tab Host inside Dialog :

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "dialog", 1).show();    
                   // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialo);
                    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

                    tabs.setup();

                    TabHost.TabSpec tabpage1 = tabs.newTabSpec("one");
                    tabpage1.setContent(R.id.tabview1);
                    tabpage1.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one));

                    TabHost.TabSpec tabpage2 = tabs.newTabSpec("two");
                    tabpage2.setContent(R.id.tabview2);
                    tabpage2.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.two));

                    tabs.addTab(tabpage1);
                    tabs.addTab(tabpage2);



                    dialog.show();
                  }
    });
```